# UITextView undo position

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, nsundomanager

I make a few changes to the begin, middle and end in a `UITextView`. Then I perform a step by step undoing by:

```
[self.textView.undoManager undo]
```

I'd like to programmatically scroll the `UITextView` to each corresponding `undo` position, after each `undo`.

How can I retrieve the last/upcoming `undo` position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the last undo position from the text view, that's a private implementation detail.

However, the text view should automatically position the caret after each undo step to where the undo happened, so you could probably just use `[textView scrollRangeToVisible:textView.selectedRange]` to go there.